# Algebraic K-theory: Categories of modules and their equivalences

Tags: algebraic-topology, category-theory, modules, projective-module

I'm currently preparing a presentation on the second chapter, called "Categories of modules and their equivalences", in Algebraic K-theory by Hyman Bass. I have a VERY elementary understanding of category theory and don't really know much about what the applications of the topics and results in this chapter actually are. Since this reading was assigned for a seminar class where we give presentations on "seminal papers in algebraic topology", I'm assuming there is quite a bit going on here that I'm not aware of. I'm looking for some advice, comments, etc. that could help me get a better idea of the relevance of these topics and what role they played in the development of K-theories and other areas of algebraic topology over the last 40 years or so. Anything will help but I'm specifically looking for concrete examples and applications as well as anything that can help me frame this work historically.
Some of the main topics in the chapter are

1. Characterizing categories of modules
2. "faithfully projective objects"
3. R-categories: Right continuous functors
4. (pre-)equivalence data
5. Constructing an equivalence from a module
6. Autoequivalences
7. The Picard group

Much thanks ahead of time for any comments. Literally anything you might have to say that seems remotely relevant would be appreciated at this point (I've only had yesterday and until 4pm est today to prepare...)

Comment: If you are only allotted less than two days to prepare something like this, then be sure to limit how deep you go. If you didn't know about [Weibel's book online](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~weibel/Kbook.html) you might consider checking it out.

Comment: Usually, questions in the style of yours, which is essentially a «Please tell me stuff about X!» are a bad fit to the Question&Answer format of this site. Your list of bullets is half of the contents table of any sensible textbook on the subject... I suggest you ask more focused questions.

Comment: In any case, pick any textbook on rings and modules which has a chapter on «Morita theory» and read that (Anderson&Fuller, Weibel, McConner&Robson, Pierce, Jacobson are examples of books that cover the subject)

Comment: For pre equivalence data, Morita equivalence and such, I would suggest Jacobson's Basic Algebra (volume II) pag. 164 and the summary in this nLab page: http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Morita+context

Comment: Also, it would probably be a goo idea to remove all references to K-theory in the tag and in the title, which doe snot have much to do with the actual question. If you really have a very elementary understanding of category theory and so on, the project of getting «a better idea of the relevance of these topics and what role they played in the development of K-theories and other areas of algebraic topology over the last 40 years or so» in two days is rather unfeasable :-/

Comment: I removed the K-theory tags. I kept algebraic k-theory in the text though since thats the title of the book... I realize two days is an entirely insufficient amount of time to get a good grasp on all this stuff but thats all I had. Just trying to do the best I can with the next 3 or so hours I have left... I'm really just looking for suggestions of things to mention briefly so I can give at least some idea of why its important; even if its a very vague idea.(presentation is 30-50 minutes btw)